# How are a private key and a seed phrase related?

Tags: private-key, seed

Is it a 1-to-1 relationship? If so, does that mean they are interchangeable? Can I then store just one of them and derive the other when needed?

Answer (score 3):

It's the same relationship between the branches of a tree and the seed you put in the earth that grows into that tree.
We have a *seed* that can be used to **derive** child branches and child keys which makes the relationship is **one directional** (you can always derive the child key by having the seed but you can't compute the seed from the child key).

Take a look at the following picture from [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki):
[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, all in all, to start using Bitcoin, I can pick a random seed phrase. Then I can generate several private/public key pairs. That's what these software wallets do.

Comment: Essentially. Almost all wallets are deterministic these days. They create a random seed which they use to derive all the future keys. That way they only rely on RNG once.